# VS Code - EROFS: read-only file system, access

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed Vs Code extension that calles "background" and I am trying to set an image for background, but I am getting an error about some access and permission (something like I don't have a permission)

Error log:

```
EROFS: read-only file system, access '/private/var/folders/5z/qhktrns11j959df_gb6fvdbw0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/97FE90D3-59BF-4FAA-B2F8-1C30AEC8A89C/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css'
```

OS: MacOS Monterey 12.5

Tried to google it, but there is nothing related to this issue.
I expect there to be an image as a background in Vs Code

I will be grateful for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably related to the installation of vs code (I entirely blame apple for that). Delete the application completely. Download and extract a new vs code. Move that to "Application" from "Downloads".